# Separate search results panel for each search in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

When I press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>, I can search for all instances of a string in an entire project.

But when I do it a second time, it brings up the second search in the *same* panel. This gets *very* messy very quickly when conducting many searches.

Question: How can I bring up the second (and subsequent) search results *in their own, new* panel?

Example: 5 searches would result in 5 result sets each of their own panels (i.e. 5 panels total). Also, if possible, I'd like to set this as a default for future if it's simple to do so.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to have different search results buffer for different searches. All of the search results would be appended in the buffer with the name `Find Results`.

If you want different different search result tabs, then you will need to rename the current search result buffer with a different name than `Find Results` i.e. `Find Results (1)`. This way, the next time, you perform a find in files, ST would create a new `Find Results` buffer.

It's actually quite simple to write a small plugin that uses `View.set_name()` to set the name of the current buffer and then you can bind it to a key (So that you can just change the Find buffer name in one stroke and have other search results in new buffers)

Comment: Is there a way to grab the search term, so you could rename the buffer `Find Results (foobar*)`, for example?

Comment: `view.element()` can be used along with a little bit of a brute force search to see what `view` returns `"find_in_files:input:find`; apart from that you could pluck it directly out of the buffer since Sublime uses a fairly regular format for display what it searched for.

Comment: Yes. I agree with @OdatNurd. You can just pluck out the first line in the find buffer and use a bit of regexp (I think) to extract the search term. I'd go with that approach.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the conclusion I just came to. Thanks!